# DataTable in php

Tags: php, html, datatable

Hi i want to implement DataTable in the table to populate data from my db in my php page, the below code i used, but its not working, not getting the data table, instead i am getting the normal table only -

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/Responsive/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
<script src="../DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<div id="example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
    <div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix">
   <?php
        $sql="select product_id,product_name,original_price,offer_price,product_rating,image_main,stock_in_hand from niad_products order by product_id desc";
        $result=$linkID1->query($sql);
        $c=@mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($c>=1){?>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    responsive: true
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    <div id="printable">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#FFF">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Original Price</th>
                <th>Offer Price</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "<img width='100' height='100' src=../product-images/".$row['image_main'] ." />"; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['original_price']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['offer_price']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['product_rating']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['stock_in_hand']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
    }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php   } else {echo "No records";} ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone guide me with my mistake. It will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please check console of your browser and see what errors are coming.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:160
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:160

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at dataTables.responsive.js:867
    at dataTables.responsive.js:873

Comment: You need to add jquery js file before including the datatable js files.

Comment: @Yash, I suggest you to add it as an answer

Comment: ya its done, problem resolved, thnx

Comment: @bradbury9, thanks for your suggestion, However I would suggest beginners to do debug themselves for avoidable questions.

Comment: @Yash yup, I voted for closing 'cause of simple typo.